# Playing wav file, concatenating string to call file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am (after some strangeness with my resources file) able to play a .wav file in my project:

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
player.Stream = Sounds.L1;
Player.Play();
```

This works fine but what I want to do is be able to concatenate a string together and then call the file.  The .wav filename would be of the form "L" + int, with int being anywhere between 1 - 99 i.e. L1, L2...L99. All the different sound files are in a resx file title Sounds.

How would I be able to call them?

I am trying to use the ResXResourceSet resxSet = new ResXResourceSet("btc.Sounds") ResXResourceSet to load the resources file and then use the .getobject() as suggested.  However, how do you specify the location of the embedded resource file?  If I use a path as above I get an error as it is looking in my bin/debug folder, which is where the .exe is placed.  If I explicityly specify the path I get an access error and one thing I am really curious about is the fact that the 'Sounds.resx' file is an embedded resource so it should 'know' where it is and shouldn't need any path...  I have tried pretty much every permutation including using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("btc_I_Cap.Sounds"), @"....\Sounds" @"....\Resources", @"btc.Sounds" "Sounds.resx" and so on and so far nothing.  Can someone please put me out of my misery so that I can go 'oh yeah, that was obvious why didn't I think of that!'

Happy halloween.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ResXResrouceSet to call the sound file Something like this:

```
using (ResXResourceSet resxSet = new ResXResourceSet(resxFile))
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 99; i ++)
    {
        SoundPlayer simpleSound = (SoundPlayer)resxSet.GetObject("L" + i.ToString());
        simpleSound.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: ResXResourceSet resxSet = new ResXResourceSet(Sounds).  This gave me an error so obviously I am misunderstanding something.  Sounds being the resources file in which all the .wav files are being kept.Sais it is a type but is being used like a variable.

Comment: How are you supposed to define the location of the resx file?  I have tried as a string "Sounds", tried with my project name in front "my_project.Sounds" to no avail.  Getting lost on this one.

Comment: I tried a lot of different path names but so far I can't get the resources file to load, or should I say the Sounds.resx file to load, which is weird as it is embedded and, well, is right there...

Comment: How do you get the correct path (resxFile) for the resources file?

Comment: You do need to specify the path for the resx file.  You can use only "Sounds.resx" but just make sure that in the properties of the embedded resx file that the 'copy to output directory' is set to copy always or if newer.  If you don't then you'll get the file not found exception when you program doesn't find the file in the new directory it creates during the build.

Comment: I did manage to get it to work in the end but I have a lot of wav files in my project and I ended up getting 'out of memory' errors when I compiled the project.  In the end I simply left it as a resx file and used t large switch statement to determine which file to pull and play.  Annoying and time consuming... but it works.